# problems with linking glfw using g++

Tags: c++, glfw

so i'm trying to compile this glfw code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    return 0;
}
```

i have a batch script that looks like this:

```
g++ -Wall -O2 -ID:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\include -c src/*.cpp
g++ -LD:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib -o bin\main.exe *.o -lglfw3
```

but it returns:

```
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x10f): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x14e): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x2e3): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x8bb): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xa0b): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xde8): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xdf7): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceGammaRamp'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xe00): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xef8): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xf07): undefined reference to `__imp_SetDeviceGammaRamp'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xf10): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x1e5): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDIBSection'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x21f): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateBitmap'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x2c8): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x350): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x3e4): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateRectRgn'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x41b): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `__imp_SwapBuffers'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x3f6): undefined reference to `__imp_ChoosePixelFormat'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x404): undefined reference to `__imp_SetPixelFormat'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0xb2f): undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x107a): undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x1095): undefined reference to `__imp_SetPixelFormat'
D:\programowanie\C++\openGL\Libraries\lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x1376): undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

i downloaded glfw with: windows pre-commpiled binaries with mingw

Comment: You should go through the glfw build guide here: https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html, specifically the section titled "Link with the right libraries"

Answer (score 0):

I think its too late but still here's the solution:

just replace `-lglfw3` at the end with `-lglfw3dll` and add the glfw3.dll file to your output folder which is the "bin" folder this should do

I'm not really sure why replacing this fixes the issue cause i dont really know about glfw but just experimented with it one

Comment: It says why in the documentation link that Frank posted as a comment to the qustion. "The static version of the GLFW library is named glfw3. When using this version, it is also necessary to link with some libraries that GLFW uses." Judging from the symbols, it looks like there are missing some windows api dlls